# How do you disable the zoom effect / window animations in the new OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, window-manager

I'd like to disable the Zoom effect that the windows produce when they are being opened. Does anyone know a way to disable them?

Answer (score 6):

Open Terminal.app In your /Applications/Utilies folder and run the following command:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO
```

and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Note: Changes might only take place after restarting your mac

Comment: The command is `defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSAutomaticWindowAnimationsEnabled -bool NO` and the change is instant. The next app you launch will just appear rather than zooming into existence. No need to restart.

Comment: That's great :P I didn't want to try it myself because I rather like the new animations, but I can understand how a slower machine might have problems with it.